# How to override PHPMAILER exceptions?

Tags: php, phpmailer

i'm sending emails via phpmailer and i want to override the exceptions as when you send an email and that fail you can have the error message via :

```
echo json_encode"{$mail->ErrorInfo}";
```

but when the error is

```
"Empty body"
```

i would like to display something else.
Any solution ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
$new_msg = json_encode"{$mail->ErrorInfo}";

if ($new_msg == 'Empty body') {
  throw new CustomException("You custom message ");
}
```

Wherever you are calling this function, catch the expectation there and show it to the user.

```
try {
        if ($new_msg == 'Empty body') {
          throw new CustomException("You custom message ");
       } 
    } catch (CustomException $ex) {
        //This is where you can have your own handling, exceptions that you want to handle separately 
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
       // this part will handle general exceptions
        // and show user some general error message
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put your echo in a variable and then do an if check to display something else.

```
$new_msg = json_encode"{$mail->ErrorInfo}";

if ($new_msg == 'Empty body') {
 echo 'You put here whatever you want';
} else {
 echo json_encode"{$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just catch the Exception and do something completely different!

```
try {
   $something->thatWillThrowAnException();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Do anything you want here!
}
```